# "Invalid value for module argument" with list of CIDR blocks

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, cloudposse

I’m trying to add multiple rules to a cloudposse [security group](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/cloudposse/security-group/aws/latest). Here is the relevant code:

```hcl
module "subnets" {
  source = "cloudposse/dynamic-subnets/aws"
  version = "0.39.8"

  vpc_id              = module.vpc.vpc_id
  igw_id              = module.vpc.igw_id
  cidr_block          = module.vpc.vpc_cidr_block
  availability_zones  = local.az_names
  # nat_gateway_enabled = true

  context = module.this.context
}

module "sg" {
  source = "cloudposse/security-group/aws"
  version = "0.4.3"

  attributes = ["primary"]

  rules = [
    {
      key         = "HTTP"
      type        = "ingress"
      from_port   = 80
      to_port     = 80
      protocol    = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks = module.subnets.public_subnet_cidrs
      self        = null
      description = "Allow HTTP from IPs in our public subnets (which includes the ALB)"
    },
    {
      key         = "SSH"
      type        = "ingress"
      from_port   = 22
      to_port     = 22
      protocol    = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      self        = null
      description = "Allow SSH from all IPs"
    }
  ]

  vpc_id  = module.vpc.vpc_id
  context = module.this.context
}
```

This is failing with:

> Error: Invalid value for module argument
> The given value is not suitable for child module variable “rules” defined
> at .terraform/modules/project_module.sg/variables.tf:60,1-17: element types
> must all match for conversion to list.

And the problem is the `cidr_blocks`. If I replace the first one with `["0.0.0.0/0"]` it works. I see that the [output from the `aws-dynamic-subnets` module](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-dynamic-subnets/blob/master/outputs.tf) is `aws_subnet.public.*.cidr_block`. The current value of the `cidr_blocks` variable in the resource is `["172.16.96.0/19", "172.16.128.0/19"]`, which sure looks like a list of strings to me. When I open `terraform console` and ask for the type of `public_subnet_cidrs`, I just get `dynamic`. I’ve tried wrapping the output in `tolist()` and adding an empty string to the cidr_blocks array (to create lists of the same length) in the second ingress rule, but neither changes the error.

I have successfully worked around this issue by using a `rule_matrix` for the HTTP rule and then also defining `rules` with a single rule dictionary for the SSH rule, but this feels rather hacky.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, what is your terraform version?

Comment: I am using Terraform 1.1.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rule_maps`, instead of `rules`:

```
module "sg" {
  source = "cloudposse/security-group/aws"
  version = "0.4.3"

  attributes = ["primary"]

  rules_map = {
        "HTTP" = [{
          key         = "HTTP"
          type        = "ingress"
          from_port   = 80
          to_port     = 80
          protocol    = "tcp"
          cidr_blocks = module.subnets.public_subnet_cidrs
          self        = null
          description = "Allow HTTP from IPs in our public subnets (which includes the ALB)"
        }],
       "SSH" = [{
          key         = "SSH"
          type        = "ingress"
          from_port   = 22
          to_port     = 22
          protocol    = "tcp"
          cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
          self        = null
          description = "Allow SSH from all IPs"
        }
      ]
    }

  vpc_id  = module.vpc.vpc_id
  context = module.this.context
}
```

This is a little bit cleaner then using both `rules` and `rule_matrix`. Also I'm not sure why just using `rules` does not work. I guess it does some inner processing of `cidr_blocks`, and expects them to be exactly same type (list with 3 non-empty string elements).

Comment: This worked, thank you! I was also able to remove the `key` attribute from each rule.

Comment: Yes, Terraform is very strict about list objects all being identical types. The `cloudposse/terraform-aws-security-group` [README](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-security-group/blob/master/README.md) explains this in great detail. `rules_map` was created specifically to get around this issue.